# Excel - Macro to open a file or web page or internal link on clicking a button

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to open a file or page by clicking a button in main sheet(sheet1) the file might be an excel or https: or www.google.com from a cell (C2) in sheet2.

i wrote a macro for a button click - it works fine if its an excel file but if its a https: it doesn't work and tries to open in excel because i m not sure how to differentiate the code.

how would i open the https or wwww as well by clicking the button
Here is the  code

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim xlApp As Application
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Dim wrkMyWorkBook As Workbook
    Set wrkMyWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Value)

End Sub
```

The cell c2 in sheet2 will get have "full text/link" upon selection made in  different cells in main sheet(sheet1)
for example: cell c2 in sheet2 will only have one of the following full path of the file or page to be open
H:\Test report\Report1.xlsm
or 
http://server:in:au:7250/Visualviwer/Analytics.jsp
or 
www.google.com

Thanks
karthik

Answer (score 0):

When you want to open web page using VBA you have to create IE object to achieve this.

```
Sub CallJSPPage()
Dim objIE As Object
On Error GoTo error_handler
Application.EnableEvents = True
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objIE
.Navigate " http://server:in:au:7250/Visualviwer/Analytics.jsp"
objIE.Visible = True

End With

Exit Sub

error_handler:
MsgBox ("Unexpected Error, I'm quitting.")
' objIE.Quit
Set objIE = Nothing


End Sub
```

You can also open chrome browser via VBA. But the above is the one you are expecting.

Hope it helps